# Sybase function Illegal INSERT statement within a scalar SQL function

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I know in syabse function return scalar value , is there an alternative way that I can insert in sybase function ?

```
drop function udf_getdate
go
create function udf_getdate
returns datetime
as
begin
insert into ex_employee (id) values(1)
return @datevalue
end
go
```

> Illegal INSERT statement within a scalar SQL function.

Comment: Realistically it doesn't make sense to use an insert to a table as a function - a stored procedure is more sensible.

Comment: @RichCampbell the reason for the function is to use it in a select .

Comment: Yes but imagine someone randomly did a select * from  a massive table with the function - I'm not sure you would actually want to insert a row to this ex_exployee table by mistake surely when you appear to creating a date-based function? Again it doesn't seem to make logical sense from your example.